# Error when subclassing pcl::Feature

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, point-cloud-library

I am following along this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_new_classes.php) for subclassing PCL classes. However I am trying to subclass the `pcl::Feature` which takes two typename templates and when I try to use the `PCL_INSTANTIATE` macro and `#define PCL_INSTANTIATE_SurfaceDetector` I run into the following error:

```
error: macro 
"PCL_INSTANTIATE_SurfaceDetector" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
 PCL_INSTANTIATE(SurfaceDetector, (PCL_XYZ_POINT_TYPES)(PCL_XYZ_POINT_TYPES))
 ^
```

and also this:

```
surfacedetector.cpp:6: error: 'PCL_INSTANTIATE_SurfaceDetector' does not name a type
 PCL_INSTANTIATE(SurfaceDetector, (PCL_XYZ_POINT_TYPES)(PCL_XYZ_POINT_TYPES))
 ^
```

I tried inheriting from `pcl::pclBase` instead and that worked! I guess the problem is with how I am handeling the extra type. These are my .cpp .h and .hpp files:

### surfacedetector.hpp:

```
#ifndef SURFACEDETECTOR_IMPL_H_
#define SURFACEDETECTOR_IMPL_H_

#include <surfacedetector.h>

// code ...

#define PCL_INSTANTIATE_SurfaceDetector(T1,T2) template class PCL_EXPORTS SurfaceDetector<T1,T2>;

#endif // SURFACEDETECTOR_H_
```

### surfacedetector.h:

```
#ifndef SURFACEDETECTOR_H_
#define SURFACEDETECTOR_H_

// PCL
#include <pcl/features/feature.h>
#include <pcl/search/search.h>

// code...

#endif // SURFACEDETECTOR_H
```

### surfacedetector.hpp

```
#ifndef SURFACEDETECTOR_IMPL_H_
#define SURFACEDETECTOR_IMPL_H_

#include <surfacedetector.h>

// code ...

#define PCL_INSTANTIATE_SurfaceDetector(T1,T2) template class PCL_EXPORTS SurfaceDetector<T1,T2>;

#endif // SURFACEDETECTOR_H_
```

### Update

When I use `PCL_INSTANTIATE_PRODUCT` instead of `PCL_INSTANTIATE`, it compiles fine but when I try to use my class I get this error:

```
error: cannot declare field 'CloudProcessing::surfaceDetector' to be of abstract type 'SurfaceDetector<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZ>'
     SurfaceDetector<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::PointXYZ> surfaceDetector;
                                                      ^
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that pcl::Feature is an abstract class and it has the pure virtual function `void computeFeature(PointCloudOut &output)` which I must override in order to use as a concrete class in my code.

Furthurmore using `PCL_INSTANTIATE_PRODUCT` solved the issue with the macro.